# How can I hide an element that is empty by class name?

Tags: php, html

I am using a custom theme on my WordPress site and so I have set that in single.php if there's a thumbnail it will show it fluid above the content. I used this:

```
<div class="fotocopertina">
<?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endif;
        ?></div>
```

Giving the class: fotocopertina a specific height. Now I also set the class: `.fotocopertina:empty {display: none;}` because I wanted that box to not be shown when there's not thumbnail set. Yet it still there, it doesn't disappear even if it's empty. Even tho analyzing the page I get this:

```
<div class="fotocopertina"></div>
```

So it's actually "empty". How can I fix this? Thanks!

Edit:

This is the CSS I am using:

```
.fotocopertina {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 280px;
    
}

.fotocopertina img{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 280px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #072545;
}

.fotocopertina:empty{
   display:none;
}

.fotocopertina img:empty{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, It will help you.

`<div class="fotocopertina" <?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()){ echo 'style="display:none;"'; } ?> >`

```
   <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;`enter code here`
    ?>
```

`</div>`